# Seaborn stripplot with violin plot bars in front of points

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to draw a violin plot behind a jitter stripplot. The resulting plot has the mean/std bar behind the jitter points which makes it hard to see. I'm wondeing if there's a way to bring the bar in front of the points.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color="0.8")
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, jitter=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: violin]

Comment: how about a swarmplot?

Comment: yeah might work but I'd still like to be able to plot the mean/std markers over the points

Comment: No one can provide a concrete working solution unless you provide people with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and could fix it simply by adjusting the `zorder`parameter in `sns.stripplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color="0.8")
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, jitter=True, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

The result then similar to the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seaborn doesn't care about exposing the objects it creates to the user. So one would need to collect them from the axes to manipulate them. The property you want to change here is the `zorder`. So the idea can be to

1. Plot the violins
2. Collect the lines and dots from the axes, and give the lines a high zorder, and give the dots an even higher zorder.
3. Last plot the strip- or swarmplot. This will have a lower zorder automatically.

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color=".8")

for artist in ax.lines:
    artist.set_zorder(10)
for artist in ax.findobj(PathCollection):
    artist.set_zorder(11)

sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, jitter=True, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]